# How to get all columns of a table,whereas TableName is a Output Paramater?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

I want a stored procedure to display all the columns of it but I would select table name externally like EXEC spDisplay 'tblName'.. I want Table name as a output parameter...How can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use dynamic SQL, like below..

```
create proc spDisplay
@TableName as varchar(100)
as
Begin
    exec('select top 10 * from '+@TableName)
End
```

Answer (score 1):

Below is the SP, It will take Table Name as Input Parameter.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE MySp
@TableName VARCHAR(MAX)
AS
BEGIN

DECLARE @Sql VARCHAR(MAX)

SET @Sql = 'SELECT * FROM ' + @TableName

EXEC(@Sql)

END
```

Below is the query to execute above Sp, Here emp is my table name

EXEC MySp 'emp'